# codeigniter ajax post data to controller export csv

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have a table with a list of the users, and I want to save multiple records using a checkbox in Codeigniter application, I use jquery ajax to send multiple rows to my controller. On the button click, I would like to get the email of each checked user from the database and save the result in a CSV.

/*      My script                */

```
$('#button').click(function(){

    var checkbox = $('.rows_checkbox:checked');
    if(checkbox.length > 0)
    {
        var checkbox_value = [];
        $(checkbox).each(function(){
            checkbox_value.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>backoffice/candidates/csv_all",
            method:"POST",
            data:{checkbox_value:checkbox_value},
            success:function()
            {
                alert('success');
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Select atleast one records');
    }
});
```

/* Controller  */

```
public function csv_all()
{

    if($this->input->post('checkbox_value'))
    {
        $file_name = 'student_details_on_'.date('Ymd').'.csv';
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
        header("Content-Type: application/csv;");

        $id = $this->input->post('checkbox_value');
        for($count = 0; $count < count($id); $count++)
        {
            $student_data = $this->users_model->get_csv($id[$count]);
        }
        // file creation
        $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        $header = array("email");
        fputcsv($file, $header);
        foreach ($student_data->result_array() as $key => $value)
        {
            fputcsv($file, $value);
        }
        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

/*======  Model    ====*/

```
public function get_csv($id)

{
    $this->db->select('email');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $query_rslt = $query->row_array();
        return $query_rslt['email'];
    }
    else { return FALSE; }
}
```

when I click the button, I receive the alert but it does not generate the csv file

Comment: Can you explain your problem further? That's a lot of code - and all you know is that it's not working?

Comment: I have a table with list of the users , and I wand to save multiple records using a checkbox in Codeigniter application, i use jquery ajax for send multiple rows in my controller. I click on the button I would like to select the email of each user from database , and save the result in a Csv

Comment: Please add all such clarification to the question, not to the comment section. And still, you've only stated what you want to achieve. Can you explain which of these parts do **not** work yet, and what you've tried to debug this problem given all that code?

Comment: I did what you asked, I hope it's clear to you now

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked which data is sent to the backend? Does PHP itself show any error message?

Comment: you can't download a file via ajax - atleast, not easily. best to use a traditional post for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)